# DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Tags: php

I am new to php.

**Below is my code:**

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 

    function convertLdapTimeStamp($timestamp){
        $time = strtotime($timestamp);  
        return date('d M, Y H:i:s A T',$time);
    }

$convertedLdapTimeStamp = convertLdapTimeStamp('20150807080212Z');
$now = new DateTime();

$diff=$now->diff($convertedLdapTimeStamp);

?>
```

**Here is the error I am getting:** `PHP Warning:  DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in /home/fkpeNb/prog.php on line 16`

You can even check the output, here: `https://ideone.com/4CSOGH`

I got to understand that I am giving a String value as  a parameter, but I am not understanding how do I convert it to DateTimeInterface and then do diff(). Sorry if its dumb query.

**I even still tried as below:**

```
$convertedLdapTimeStamp = convertLdapTimeStamp('20150807080212Z');
$x = new DateTime($convertedLdapTimeStamp); // Here String converted to DateTime
$now = new DateTime(); 

$diff=$now->diff($x);
```

**for above code, getting error as:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (07 Aug, 2015 13:32:12 PM IST) at position 13 (1): Double time specification' in /home/iqPyO4/prog.php:12
```

**Here is another trial I did:** `https://ideone.com/EqYyNJ`

Comment: did you read the error? You're passing in a **STRING** (the output of `date()`), while `diff()` expects a DateTime object. You shouldn't be converting datetime objects to strings at anytime UNTIL you're ready to output it for a user. keep everything as a datetime object... there's no need for `date()`, since datetime has `->format()` which does the EXACT same thing.

Comment: @MarcB I will be glad if you could write for me one line of code sentence, so that I can get some idea on your point.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error, your convert function is returning a string that cannot be parsed by the DateTime constructor. Fortunately, you should be able to create a DateTime directly using the value you are passing to your convert function.

```
$timestamp = new DateTime('20150807080212Z');

$now = new DateTime();

$diff=$now->diff($timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$diff = $now->diff(new DateTime($x));
```

Comment: `Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (07 Aug, 2015 13:32:12 PM IST)` will be the error, OP already tried this, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To transform your string `20150807080212Z` to a DateTime object, use the following function:

```
function ldapTimeToDateTime($time)
{
    $date_time = new DateTime();
    $date_time->setTimestamp(strtotime($time));
    return $date_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
$now = new DateTime(); 
$x = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', strtotime('20150807080212Z'));
$diff = $now->diff($x);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but getting error as:  PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in..

Here: https://ideone.com/siLfbC

Comment: Thanks for your code, Just wanna know how do I use '  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); ' in your code?

Comment: Put it above everything